# How to cache external thumbs pulled from youtube videos

Tags: caching, youtube

I use this function http://pastebin.com/19YjaXZt to pull the thumbs from youtube videos I post on my site but they don't get cached. I have image caching added to my htaccess for everything else but it doesnt cache the thumbs for the videos. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I don't fully understand you (what you mean by thumb caching), but the images themselves never pass through your website, so there is little to cache there (little that htaccess can do). You just tell the browser to go look in a specific place on the youtube website for the image.

To cache them on your server (or update the cache headers that are sent with them), you will have to download the images to your server, and then server them from there to your users. Although this is technically possible, I wouldn't be surprised if this is not allowed by the Youtube terms or service. In addition, it means a lot more data traffic on your website.

I'm also wondering why you would want to do this. Youtube is fast enough generally, and at least this way your thumbnail changes if the video owner decides to change their video/thumbnail on youtube.

Comment: Im working with Google Page Speed trying to optimize my site and gives me warnings for these images saying I need to "specify a cache validator" for them. It says I need to "Serve resources from a consistent url" and it says I need to specify a caching expiration of atleast 1 week. They are currently set to 6 hours. All of thos items give me a red dot for performance.

Comment: Caching settings is always a choice between speed and flexibility (to be able to change your data). So youtube choose 6 hours as their tradeoff. I'm not sure that you will really notice the difference as an actual user; only when you come to your site, and come back after 6 hours to view the same thumbnails. And even then it takes maybe half a second longer to load them all. Getting all green dots in a GPS is not a goal in itself (if you just delete all content from your page I'm sure it will be very green and fast, just not useful), and in this case you don't really have a choice it seems.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. One thing else it tells me its serving the same image from different url's. Like one image from http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/MUbNmjc_jeg/default.jpg
http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/MUbNmjc_jeg/default.jpg
http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/MUbNmjc_jeg/default.jpg Is something wrong with my function?

Comment: Problem is `$img_server_num =  'i'. rand(1,4);`, it chooses a random server. The idea is that a browser will only make so many (typically 3 or 4) connections to the same host. So by adding a random number there, the browser will download more images in parallel. If you never show more than 3 thumbnails on one page, you could easily remove the random there. Alternatively you can depend the servername on the image: `$img_server_num =  'i'. (crc32($vid_id[1]) % 4 + 1;`. This will make sure that one image always comes from the same server while still distributing different images over servers.

Comment: I got an error when I replaced that string saying unexpected ';'. Oh there was just a mssing ')'. Works great! thanks!